# Matching two queries to check Datatype

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following problem:

I transfer data automatically from a CSV file to a SQL database. In this database, not every data type is "varchar", but sometimes "decimal" or something like that. First, the representations of the important things (in the console):

newrecordarray:

```
[ { Referenz: 'Beispieltext1',
    Client: 'Beispieltext2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispieltext4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext5',
    Bank: 'Beispieltext6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispieltext7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispieltext8',
    Valuta: 'Beispieltext9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispieltext10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispieltext11',
    Wrg: 'Beispieltext12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext13,
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispieltext15' },
  { Referenz: 'Beispieltext1',
    Client: 'Beispieltext2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispieltext4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext5',
    Bank: 'Beispieltext6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispieltext7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispieltext8',
    Valuta: 'Beispieltext9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispieltext10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispieltext11',
    Wrg: 'Beispieltext12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext13,
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispieltext15' },
  { Referenz: 'Beispieltext1',
    Client: 'Beispieltext2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispieltext4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext5',
    Bank: 'Beispieltext6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispieltext7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispieltext8',
    Valuta: 'Beispieltext9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispieltext10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispieltext11',
    Wrg: 'Beispieltext12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext13,
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispieltext15' }]
```

keysY:

```
[ 'Referenz',
  'Client',
  'Clienthauptgruppe',
  'Kontrahent',
  'Kontrahentenhauptgruppe',
  'Bank',
  'Back_to_Back',
  'Int_Ext',
  'Valuta',
  'Geschaeftsart',
  'Kauf_Verkauf',
  'Wrg',
  'Diff_In_Hauswaehrung',
  'Hauswaehrung',
  'Marktwert_NPV' ]
```

here is the DATA_TYPE:

```
[ { COLUMN_NAME: 'Referenz', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Client', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Clienthauptgruppe', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Kontrahent', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Kontrahentenhauptgruppe', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Bank', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Back_to_Back', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Int_Ext', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Valuta', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Geschaeftsart', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Kauf_Verkauf', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Wrg', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Diff_in_Hauswaehrung', DATA_TYPE: 'decimal' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Hauswaehrung', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Marktwert_NPV', DATA_TYPE: 'decimal' } ]
```

Here the important loop

```
 newrecordarray.forEach(entry => {


                    if ( HERE IS THE PROBLEM! ) {

                        values = `"${entry[keysY[0]]}"`

                    } else {

                        values = `${entry[keysY[0]]}`

                    }


                    for (var i = 1; i < keysY.length; i++) {

                        if ( HERE IS THE PROBLEM! ) {

                            values += `,"${entry[keysY[i]]}"`
                        } else {

                            values += `,${entry[keysY[i]]}`
                        }

                    }

                    //console.log(values)
```

Now I want check in the "if loop" if for example the "Referenz" has the DATA_TYPE "varchar" and then put the value in quotation marks and if it has for example the DATA_TYPE "decimal" then put the value without quotation marks.

in SQL it looks like that:

INSERT INTO "Tablename" (Name of Tables...) VALUES ("Beispieltext1", "Beispieltext2","...","...",...,"...",...)

I dont't know how i can solve this easily.

Best regards

Frederic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var rec = [ { Referenz: 'Beispieltext1',
    Client: 'Beispieltext2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispieltext4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispieltext5',
    Bank: 'Beispieltext6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispieltext7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispieltext8',
    Valuta: 'Beispieltext9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispieltext10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispieltext11',
    Wrg: 'Beispieltext12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext13',
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispieltext14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispieltext15' }];

var dataSet = [ { COLUMN_NAME: 'Referenz', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Client', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Clienthauptgruppe', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Kontrahent', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Kontrahentenhauptgruppe', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Bank', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Back_to_Back', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Int_Ext', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Valuta', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Geschaeftsart', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Kauf_Verkauf', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Wrg', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Diff_in_Hauswaehrung', DATA_TYPE: 'decimal' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Hauswaehrung', DATA_TYPE: 'varchar' },
  { COLUMN_NAME: 'Marktwert_NPV', DATA_TYPE: 'decimal' } ]

dataSet  = dataSet.reduce( (nObj, obj) => {
 nObj[obj.COLUMN_NAME] = obj.DATA_TYPE;
 return nObj;
},{})

var numberPattern = /\d+/g;



rec = rec.map( (obj) => {
 return Object.keys(obj).reduce( (nObj, key) => { 
   if(dataSet[key] != 'varchar')
      nObj[key] = parseFloat(obj[key].match( numberPattern ).join(''));
   else
     nObj[key] = obj[key];
   return nObj; 
 },{})
}) 

rec;
```

Comment: very very good!! Many Thanks! But there is a problem with the numbers... for example 45000.07 is now 4500007 ... How can I fix it?

Comment: change the regex to - `var numberPattern = /\d*\.?\d*/g;`

Comment: it works but one problem existed: negative numbers ;) but I solved this with /-?\d*\.?\d*/g;

Answer (score 0):

i) You can simply create an array called 'decimalFields' containing all the fileds with datatype decimal.
ii) while constructing the query, you can skip the quotes if any field is present in 'decimalFields' array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt for resolving your issue.

```
dataSet  = dataSet.reduce( (nObj, obj) => {
 nObj[obj.COLUMN_NAME] = obj.DATA_TYPE;
 return nObj;
},{})

var numberPattern = /\d+/g;



rec = rec.map( (obj) => {
 return Object.keys(obj).reduce( (nObj, key) => { 
   if(dataSet[key] != 'varchar')
      nObj[key] = parseInt(obj[key].match( numberPattern ).join(''));
   else
     nObj[key] = obj[key];
   return nObj; 
 },{})
}) 

rec;
```

Comment: rec = rec.map((obj) => {
                    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((nObj, key) => {
                        if (dataSet[key] != 'varchar')
                            nObj[key] = parseFloat(obj[key].match(numberPattern));
                        else
                            nObj[key] = obj[key];
                        return nObj;
                    }, {})
                })


I have deleted join('') and now i get the numbers but without the decimal